# Find numbers in string using Golang regexp

Tags: regex, go

I want to find all numbers in a string with the following code:

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
fmt.Println(re.FindAllString("abc123def", 0))
```

I also tried adding delimiters to the regex, using a positive number as second parameter for `FindAllString`, using a numbers only string like "123" as first parameter...

But the output is always `[]`

I seem to miss something about how regular expressions work in Go, but cannot wrap my head around it. Is `[0-9]+` not a valid expression?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is with your second integer argument. Quoting from the package doc of [`regex`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/):

> These routines take an extra integer argument, n; if n >= 0, the function returns at most n matches/submatches.

You pass `0` so at most 0 matches will be returned; that is: *none* (not really useful).

Try passing `-1` to indicate you want all.

Example:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
fmt.Println(re.FindAllString("abc123def987asdf", -1))
```

Output:

```
[123 987]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LWn1vahhok).

Comment: Wow, I was sure that I had tried it at least with `1` but looks like I had another error then, cannot reproduce it anymore. `-1` works great, thanks

Comment: `regexp.MustCompile("\\d+")`

Answer (score 0):

@icza answer is perfect for fetching positive numbers but, if you have a string which contains negative numbers also like below

```
"abc-123def987asdf"
```

and you are expecting output like below

```
[-123 987]
```

replace regex expression with below

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[-]?\d[\d,]*[\.]?[\d{2}]*`)
```